# Antlr4 maven and Java 1.8

Tags: maven, java-8, antlr4

I am using Antlr4 to parse language. 
I also use maven to build my target JAR.

It all works fine with JDK 1.7, but my parser tool should run as a part of a Java 8 based system. I tried to compile it as Java 1.8 but got excpetion that 1.8 is not supported.

Is there a solution?

regards,
id

Answer (score 3):

Java 8 has been supported since ANTLR release 4.2.

Source: [Release notes for ANTLR 4](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/releases/tag/4.2)